# AVS not applicable for this transaction

Tags: drupal-7, authorize.net

I am using `ubercart` module with `uc_authorizenet` in a Drupal site, Now the transaction is not done properly and a message displayed in admin comment

```
Authorization only
REJECTED: This transaction cannot be accepted.
Amount: XXX
AVS response: P - AVS not applicable for this transaction
CVV match: -
```

i am testing it in live mode and also disable the AVS filter but still have issue.

Comment: Are you sure its the AVS response that is causing the transaction to fail? Is it a foreign credit card? The processor may not allow it to be processed.

Comment: Is it a foreign credit card? -- Yes, but i enable ip filter to accept payment from my country @jhon

Comment: But the merchant account provider may not accept it and that appears to be the case here. There's nothing you can do about that other than switching to a merchant account provider that does.

Comment: Just change the transaction key and its works like a charm. Thank you @JohnConde